# How to create an economy for low skilled people in a high-cost country?

Tags: economy

Think of a substantial amount of migration taking place within a larger country with significant differences in income levels in different parts of the country, but a still federal but somewhat homogenized legal system. In other words, some people from "poor" provinces have a right to settle in the "richer" provinces and receive public benefits, at least to a certain extend.

What ideas would make sense to create an economy for those people in order for them to have a chance to become independent of wellfare after a reasonable amount of time (some years as opposed to generations) given that they have little skills at all, at least not the kind that the majority is willing to pay

Comment: What ideas would make sense to create an economy for those people in order for them to have a chance (**What % chance**) to become independent of wellfare after a reasonable amount of time (some years as opposed to generations) given that they have little skills at all, at least not the kind that the majority is willing to pay

Comment: I would suggest a free market economy. *"I am for doing good to the poor, but I differ in opinion of the means. I think the best way of doing good to the poor, is not making them easy in poverty, but leading or driving them out of it. In my youth I traveled much, and I observed in different countries, that the more public provisions were made for the poor, the less they provided for themselves, and of course became poorer. And, on the contrary, the less was done for them, the more they did for themselves, and became richer.*" - Ben Franklin.

Comment: Traditionally, that would have been a manufacturing-based economy. See recently: China.

Comment: @DA are you suggesting to low-skilled americans to move to China? That would be second leg of free trade: first (chinese goods) are already quite visible in US.

Comment: @lowtech I'm not suggesting anything other than low-skilled workers tend to do better in economies that depend on low-skilled labor.

Comment: @DA: I think you named the issue very well. China has a virtually indefinite supply of cheap low-skilled labor. (They of course have all the rest as well, but this is another issue.) So I guess there is little success in trying to compete with Chinese labor cost.

Comment: Also the idea would be upskilling, just possibly in smaller iterations. What I mean by that is: You can tell a person with virtually zero skills that after spending the next 10-15 years in schools (learning to read and write, math, high school diploma, vocational training, college, ...) they may get a job as good as anyone else. Just there will be very few people willing to go all the way down that road.

Comment: I don't know that that is true. But it sounds like you're proposing a system that moves people away from low skilled jobs. That exists, of course, through training and education (provided the economy is there to provide jobs on the other side). I wouldn't say very few are willing as many do go through that path. Many can't, of course, due to other reasons (often money). That said, many high-cost countries are also wealthy countries and highly subsidize higher education to get around that issue.

Comment: Services. You don't need a great deal of skill to provide service. Just honesty and work ethic. I would pay every day for someone **I can trust** to: (1) Pick up my kids from school and watch them play for 1 hr; (2) Take a Citibike from where I need to go and drive it to where I am {I fight the rush hour and frequently there's no bikes left}; (3) Give me unskilled massage; (4) Stay in line in the store for me. There are NO SKILLS needed; you can't offshore any of those jobs to China; all that's needed is being trusted by me.

Comment: BTW, this is already practiced to an extent. There are people being paid to move Citibikes against rush hour direction.

Comment: The answer is simple... just remove the welfare that artificially inflates the economy and supports a structure that rewards low earners.  Prices come down to serve the need, and people who choose not to work suddenly start working to survive.

Comment: @DVK Where do these new jobs come from? What is keeping those jobs from appearing today?

Comment: @Skúli - several reasons. 1. Government regulation (did you know that several service intdustries have government required licenses, mainly designed to lower competition by raising cost of entry?). 2. Poor economy (you don't up your service consumption in a recession. 3. Poor worker pool. I said I would hire someone I can TRUST. I don't trust most of those people raised in welfare/"self esteem"/metal for participation"/working hard is for chumps" society to work hard and honestly on my behalf. 4. They do appear. freshdirect.com. Citibike drivers. Etc...

Comment: @DVK I suspect 2 and 3 would make it hard for those jobs to appear in great enough numbers.